# Horner's method to return P(x) and its derivative

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def horner(x,coeffs):
    result = 0
    deriv = 0
    for a in coeffs:
        result = x*result+a
        deriv = x*deriv+result
    return result,deriv
```

this is what I have got. But the value of deriv is not correct which I dont know why..

Comment: Many of the viewers may not know what is horner's method. Do add sample inputs and expected values

Comment: in wikipedia there is python implementation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method#Python_implementation

Comment: Indeed for coeffs=[7] you get (7,7) instead of correct answer (7,0). What would happen if "deriv" didn't use updated "result" from the same iteration...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this function to differenciate:

```
def differenciate(coefficients):
    return [c * (len(coefficients) - i) for i, c in enumerate(coefficients[:-1])]
```

and this function to evaluate a polinomial:

```
def call(coefficients, x):
    return sum(x ** (len(coefficients) - i - 1) * c for i, c in enumerate(coefficients))
```

There might be no need to do both in one function. You can do

```
call(differenciate([1, 2, 3, 4]), 4)
```

[Used here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/niccokunzmann/positioning_system/blob/master/nullstellen.ipynb#13)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is right, just need to switch the result and deriv lines round because in your first deriv value you want to be using your result = 0 to get the correct answer :)